# How do you "import" image data for MNIST?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, image-recognition, mnist

So I've been using Tensorflow's tutorials for neural networks. I completed the "basic classification" that is essentially just MNIST and have been working on making my own custom variation as a little thought experiment. Everything is pretty self explanatory except putting the datasets into a usable form as the tutorial uses a premade dataset and looks like it cuts some corners. All I would like to know is how to put a colored photo into a usable piece of data. I assume that will just be a 1D array. As a side question, will a neural network lose any effectiveness if a 2d photo is stored in a 1d array if its not a CNN.

Comment: The minst number and fashion datasets with keras/tensorflow are monochromatic 2d arrays. A color photo would have color channels, so that's a 3 dimensional array.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info. So as per my question, how do I import?

Comment: @MikeSperry ^^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Datasets included in Keras are premade and usually preprocessed so that beginner could easily try a hand on them. For using your own images, like for a cat-dog image classification problem, you can place the images in two separate directories, for example,
in `images/cats` and `images/dogs`.
Now, we parse each and every image in these directories,

```
import os
from PIL import Image

master_dir = 'images'
img_dirs = os.listdir( master_dir ) 
for img_dir in img_dirs:
    img_names = os.listdir( os.path.join( master_dir , img_dir ) ) 
    for name in img_names:
        img_path = os.path.join( master_dir , img_dir , name ) 
        image = Image.open( img_path ).resize( ( 64 , 64 ) ).convert( 'L' ) 
        # Store this image in an array with its corresponding label
```

Here. the `image` will be an array of shape `(64, 64 )` which indicates that the image is grayscale. Besides `.convert( 'L' )` in the code, we can use `.convert( 'RGB' )` to have an image of shape `(64,64,3)` RGB image.

Now,

- Collect all the images and labels in a Python `list`.
- Convert the lists to `NumPy` arrays.
- Store the `NumPy` arrays in a `.npy` file using the `np.save()` method.
- In the file which trains the model, load these files using `np.load()` method and feed them to the model.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you can add this code in different scripts and run those scripts separately, so each script will read some files and produce processed data

Comment: So when I try to convert it into a numpy array, it still seems to think I am storing it as an "image" rather than a 2d array and will not let me convert it into a numpy array.